# Get the User Id Class Based View

Tags: django, django-views

How to get the Id of the User logged in a Class Based View ?

Here is my CBW

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
   template_name = 'polls/index.html'
   context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'
   context = 'activate'

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)  
       context['activate'] = 'Polls'
       return context

   def get_queryset(self):
       """Return the last five published questions."""
       return Question.objects.exclude(panel__user='???',  
                                       panel__valid=False)
                              .order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

Comment: It looks like these answered your question. Please mark the one correct that you used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `self.request.user`:

```
  def get_queryset(self):
       """Return the last five published questions."""
       return Question.objects.exclude(panel__user=self.request.user,  
                                       panel__valid=False)
                              .order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

Comment: You can check whether the user is authenticated with `self.request.user.is_authenticated()`

Answer (score 5):

In the Django ClassBasedViews you can get your user's id as

```
self.request.user.id
```

Answer (score 4):

you should use `self.request.user.pk` to get the login user id.To make sure user is logged in, use `loginrequiredmixin` also.

```
   from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
   class IndexView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
       template_name = 'polls/index.html'
       login_url = '/login/'
       redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
       context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'
       context = 'activate'

       def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
           context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)  
           login_user_id = self.request.user.pk
           context['activate'] = 'Polls'
           return context
```